# JQuery Getting the value of dynamically generated Option in a Select

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic-content

I'm trying to get the value of the option that the user selects on a dynamically generated option in a dynamically generated select. Right now I'm just trying to get an alert to pop up though and have been thoroughly unsuccesful.

I've tried using the .change binder inside of a docuement.ready but that didn't work and I figured it may be because the elements don't exist for it to bind to. Code for the .change

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".lowerSerialSelect").change(function () {
        alert("red")
    });
});
```

Here's the code I'm using to dynamically generate the select:

```
if (_interface == "network" && _deviceName == "Not in Use")
    {
        var lowerSerialTd = document.createElement("td");
        lowerSerialTd.className = "lowerSerial";
        trTag.appendChild(lowerSerialTd);
        var lowerSerialSelect = document.createElement("select");
        lowerSerialSelect.className = "lowerSerialSelect";
        lowerSerialSelect.name = "lowerSerial" + identifier;
        lowerSerialSelect.id = _interface + "lowerSerial" + identifier;

        var lowerSerialOption = document.createElement("option");
        lowerSerialSelect.appendChild(lowerSerialOption)

        for (newDevice in newNetworkDevices)
        {
            alert(newNetworkDevices[0]);
            var lowerSerialOption = document.createElement("option");
            lowerSerialOption.innerHTML = newNetworkDevices[newDevice][0];
            lowerSerialOption.className = "networkMacOption";
            lowerSerialOption.id = _interface + "lowerSerial" + identifier;
            lowerSerialOption.value = newNetworkDevices[newDevice];
            lowerSerialSelect.appendChild(lowerSerialOption)
        }

        lowerSerialTd.appendChild(lowerSerialSelect);
        alert("Maybe");
    }
```

So does the .change not bind to elements that aren't created yet?

If so can I get around this by rebinding everytime I create a new select? (The user will trigger the new select so it won't all be done at once)

I've also tried the $("select".on("change", "option", function() {alert("red");}); but to no avail. Any help or explanations would be appreciated.

This is on a configuration page so the code is pretty long, 800 some lines so I didn't want to post the whole thing.

Thanks

** Edit **

The html that is dynamically generated looks like this in the end:

```
  <select class="lowerSerialSelect" name="lowerSerial2" id="networklowerSerial2">
        <option></option>
        <option class="networkMacOption" id="networklowerSerial2"    value="0080A39166BA,192.168.1.59,47331,1363895658.22">0080A39166BA</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: So for anyone experiencing this same issue, my problem was a combination of using an outdated version of jquery and using an outdated version of jquery tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah you're spot on, `.change()` is not a delegated hander. Try `.on()`

```
$('body').on('change', '.lowerSerialSelect', function() {
  // code here
});
```

Comment: Hmm, I just tried that exact code with just the alert in it and it didn't trigger and I definitely have a body tag. When I figure this out I'm probably going to do all the face-palming.

Comment: Oh, I'm an idiot ok thanks a lot you were 100% correct. Turns out we were just using an antiquated version of JQuery. Now I know to leave the version code in the plugin file names.

Comment: Actually still didn't work. However I can now bind a .change whenever I create a new select. Just wish I knew why the other isn't working as it is way more efficient code.

Comment: Perhaps try isolating the issue into a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or similar. It's hard to say why it wouldn't work without seeing more code.